# In a non-const member function, why is point this non-const, while decltype pointer this is const?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a heavily templated class from which I want to use a getter. Following a common convention, I've avoided code duplication like so:

```
template< typename Foo, typename... Bars >
class Templated
{
...

  constexpr const Foo& get() const 
  { 
    return mFoo;
  }

  constexpr Foo& get() 
  { 
    return const_cast<Foo&>(const_cast<const Templated<Foo, Bars...> *>(this)->get());
  }
```

However it occurred to me that the second definition gets a bit clunky, especially with a class that has many template parameters. Luckily I figured out after a little messing around that I could simplify this for any generic class template to:

```
constexpr Foo& get()
{
  return const_cast<Foo&>(const_cast<decltype(this)>(this)->get());
```

This works because, for some reason, decltype(this) resolves to a const pointer to the class object type, whereas just (this) resolves to a non-const pointer to the class object type. Why in the world is this the case?

Comment: *"decltype(this) resolves to a const pointer to the class object type, whereas just (this) resolves to a non-const pointer to the class object type"* What? `this` is a pointer to `const` when and only when used in a `const` member function. `decltype` doesn't change that. What makes you think otherwise?

Comment: Also you don't need to write the template parameters in the cast, `const_cast<const Templated *>(this)` works just fine. See [injected-class-name](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/injected-class-name). Also you can do `std::as_const(*this).blah` instead, which is even shorter.

Comment: In what compiler does this happen, and can you post a [mcve] demonstrating that it does? I get infinite recursion from that last `get()` on both g++ and clang++, and clang++ also warns that the function always calls itself. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/aeb2a7a8a74e535f

Comment: Why is the `const_cast<...>(this)` even needed? You can call const function inside non const function without problem.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot - To avoid infinite recursion.

Comment: @StoryTeller oh, indeed.

Comment: I'm using icpc at the moment, and adding const in front of decltype(this) leads to the following error/warning: "error #191: type qualifier is meaningless on cast type". This error is due to the fact that decltype(this) is resolving to a const pointer and the extra const in front is "meaningless". Furthermore I am NOT encountering infinite recursion.

On GCC I am currently encountering the error (without adding the const): "expected primary-expression before '>' token. On the last '>'. EDIT: icpc version is 19.0.0.117 and gcc is 7.3.1

Comment: @GrahamPalmer: You would have needed `const_cast<decltype(*this) const*>(this)` but even that is unnecessary with a well-designed helper function.

Answer (score 1):

"const pointer to the class object type" isn't what you want.

`this` is immutable (`this = nullptr;` is illegal).  Not `*this`.

Make your life *much* easier by just making `add_const` and `remove_const` template functions (or use `std::as_const` if your C++ version is new enough):

```
template<typename T>
const T* add_const(T* ptr) { return ptr; } // no cast at all!

template<typename T>
T* remove_const(const T* ptr) { return const_cast<T*>(ptr); }
template<typename T>
T& remove_const(const T& ref) { return const_cast<T&>(ref); }
```

Here `add_const(this)` correctly results in `non-const pointer to const object type".

---

For that matter, from inside the class you can just add

```
auto cthis() const { return this; }
```